# Javascript Objects behaving differently?

Tags: javascript

So far I believed objects in javascript if assigned to another variable were always by reference.

For e.g

```
var x = {
    key1: "key1",
    key2: "key2"
}

var y = x
```

So if I do something like `y.key1= "modifiedKey1"`

values of `key1` in `x` witll change too. x.key1 = `modifiedKey1`

however, when I do this, `y = null` or `y= "someRandomString"`

There is NO change in `x`

x is not null, it remains the same object.

What exactly is happening?

Comment: `y` is still a normal variable you can reassign. Once you change `y`, it loses all references to `x`. Compare `changing y` with `changing something inside y`. It's not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you do set the *reference* to `null` meaning you no longer point anywhere, it does not affect the object it point*ed* to.
Same with `y = {"a" : 3}` - `x` will not change because you did not change the object `y` and `x` pointed to but you change what object `y` points to.

Comment: If you set y= "someString", there still won't be any change to x

Comment: @RahulDwivedi have you read the second sentence in my answer?

Comment: My Bad. You're completely right. The link against the question indeed answers it and I do not mind this question to be deleted.